# Codeigniter array to string conversion error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am receiving this error when posting with update_batch. I have seen other posts on this but my line reference is to the DB_active_rec.php file and others were seeing it in their MC. The error doesn't stop the update_batch from posting and it returns the error for each $rb_items.
[image]

Controller:

```
  public function update_rb(){

    $rb_items = array();
        $rb_id=$this->input->post('id', TRUE);
        $rb_brand=$this->input->post('brand', TRUE);
        $rb_tasted=$this->input->post('tasted', TRUE);
        $rb_rating=$this->input->post('rating', TRUE);
        $rb_comment=$this->input->post('comment', TRUE);

        $i=0;
        foreach($rb_id as $id){
            $rb_items[$i] = array(
                'id'=>$id,
                'brand'=>$rb_brand[$i],
                'rating'=>$rb_rating[$i],
                'comment'=>$rb_comment[$i]
                );
                if(empty($rb_tasted)){
                    $rb_items[$i]['tasted']=0;
                } else if
                (in_array($id,$rb_tasted)){
                $rb_items[$i]['tasted']=1;
                } else{
                    $rb_items[$i]['tasted']=0;
                }                   
            $i++;
        }
        $this->model->update_rb($rb_items);
    }
```

Model:

```
    public function update_rb($rb_items){
        $this->rb_db->update_batch('rb_selection',$rb_items,'id');
    }
```

View:

```
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="brand[]" value="<?php echo $row['brand'];?>">
        <td><?php echo "<p>".$row['brand']."</p>";?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" <?php if($row['tasted'] == 1){echo "checked = checked";}?> name="tasted[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" id="tasted"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rating[]" <?php echo $row['rating'];?>/></td>
        <td><textarea name='comment[]' id='comment' cols="350"><?php echo $row['comment'];?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
```

Has anyone seen this error or know what I am missing in my code? Thanks for the help!

`print_r($rb_items)` returns `Array ( [0] => Array ( [rb_id] => 192 [brand] => Napa Valley Soda Co [rating] => r0 [comment] => c0 [tasted] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [rb_id] => 193 [brand] => Natural Brew [rating] => r1 [comment] => c1 [tasted] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [rb_id] => 194 [brand] => Naturale 90 [rating] => r2 [comment] => c2 [tasted] => 1 ) )`
for a view with three brands on it. All of this is posting correctly regardless of the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an issue with my version of CI which is 2.1.2.
In the DB_active_rec.php file on line 1407,

this: 
`$not[] = $k.'-'.$v;`

should be:
`$not[] = $k2.'-'.$v2;`

The correct response was found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12910038/1738895

Answer (score 0):

Your html tags name having [] after name attributs so you will get values as an array after posting it. that is what you are getting this error.

just remove [] from name attribute and submit the form.

//Is there any specific reason you use [] after names?

Comment: As far as I know without the [] no array is created. `print_r($rb_items)` returns array(). `print_r($rb_items)` with [] returns Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 223 [brand] => Q&V [rating] => 1r [comment] => 1 [tasted] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 224 [brand] => Quick Check [rating] => 2r [comment] => 2 [tasted] => 1 ) ) when I check two of the products.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to have in your view is while iterating have a incremental value `$i` and:

```
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="comments[<?php echo $i;?>][id]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="comments[<?php echo $i;?>][brand]" value="<?php echo $row['brand'];?>">
    <td><?php echo "<p>".$row['brand']."</p>";?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" <?php if($row['tasted'] == 1){echo "checked = checked";}?> name="comments[<?php echo $i;?>][tasted]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" id="tasted"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments[<?php echo $i;?>][rating]" <?php echo $row['rating'];?>/></td>
    <td><textarea name='comments[<?php echo $i;?>][comment]' id='comment' cols="350"><?php echo $row['comment'];?></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

You make an array called `comments` which will contain an arrays of data. So if you have two rows you will get this kind of array:

```
array(
    1 => array(
        'id' => '..',
        'brand' => '..',
        'tasted' => '..',
        'rating' => '..',
        'comment' => '..'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => '..',
        'brand' => '..',
        'tasted' => '..',
        'rating' => '..',
        'comment' => '..'
    )
);
```

All you need in your controller then:

```
 $this->model->update_rb($this->input->post('comments'));
```

Don't forget about validating though!

Answer (score 0):

Pass your array to this function, it should fix your problem

```
function replaceArrayToString($arr = array()) {
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
    if (is_array($value))
    {
       unset($arr[$key]);

        //Is it an empty array, make it a string
        if (empty($value)) {
            $newArr[$key] = '';
        }
        else {
            $newArr[$key] = $this->replaceArrayToString($value);
        }

    }
    else {
        $newArr[$key] = $value; 
    }

}
return $newArr;

}
```